# How to make inverted border radius (react native)?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

How could I do such shape in react-native?

In CSS, one of the solutions is to use -webkit-mask-image, but I don't know how to do it in react-native.

[Inverted border radius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjP42.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually about CSS, not ract-native. :).

Below is my trick, you can adjust precise values.

```css
.square-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.square {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: grey;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.square:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  right: -50%;
  bottom: -50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="square-wrapper">
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give me your react native code of this ? i have the same issue .

Comment: This is not about CSS, this won't work in react-native as react-native doesn't have pseudo elements