# React Native draw custom rounded edge on View

Tags: react-native, view

I want to create a View which has one rounded edge on it in react native as you can see in the image. I already have the white view as I want it to be. However, it should extend up to the black curve. What are my options and how can it be achieved?

Thank you in advance.
 [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make inverted border radius (react native)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140427/how-to-make-inverted-border-radius-react-native)

Comment: No it isn't. The link you provided is for a border radius at a corner and inverted. I am looking for a non inverted border radius at an edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the white view elliptical by adding a bottom border radius and scaling it up using the `transform` attribute.

Then if you place it partially above the second view, you will end up with the expected output.

Here is an example:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.first} />
          <View style={styles.second} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute', 
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  first: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 50,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 50,
    transform: [{ scaleX: 4 }],
    zIndex: 1,
  },
  second: {
    backgroundColor: '#333',
    marginTop: -30,
    height: 200,
    zIndex: 0,
  },
});
```

Here is [the example in action](https://snack.expo.io/@remeus/rounded-view).